# PHP Pdo no column names in array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following query in PHP:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT 
        date, 
        avg(sells) as sells
FROM `table` WHERE product_id = :id group by date having count(id) > 1');
$stmt->execute(array('id' => $product));
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

As expected this returns me:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["date"]=> "2013-1-11" ["sells"]=> "73.5000" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        ["date"]=> "2013-1-11" ["sells"]=> "77.0000" 
    }
}
```

Anyway I can get the following output without looping with php?

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        "2013-1-11",
        "73.5000" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        "2013-1-11",
        "77.0000" 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your purpose for not knowing the columns?

Comment: I want to output the result as JSON directly. For that I need to drop the columns names

Comment: Why do you need to drop the column names for output to JSON? It makes it easier to work with to have column names even in JSON.

Comment: @jribeiro That doesn't make much sense. What's wrong with JSON objects with named properties?

Comment: Yup I know... Plugin implementation requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` use `PDO::FETCH_NUM`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that you are wanting to use JSON, try something along the following:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
```

This will give you a valid JSON structure based off of the data returned.

Comment: Yeah but that will output the column names as well.

Comment: Correct, I'm not sure why you would not want to reference the `string:value` structure for your data.